Parallel execution of a piece of x64 code
Consider the following x64 code, produced by clang:
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rsi]                        ; 1
    mov     rdx, qword ptr [rip + hash_mult]            ; 1
    imul    rdx, qword ptr [rax - 8]                    ; 2
    movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rip + hash_shift]            ; 1
    shr     rdx, cl                                     ; 3
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + vptrs]                ; 2 - or 3 ???
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rdx]                ; 4
    mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + slots_strides]        ; 1
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx]                ; 2
    jmp     rax                                         ; 5

I have two questions.

Can I assume that the lines marked with the same ordinal can and will be executed in parallel?

What's with the byte ptr used by the movzx instruction? Does it indicate poor alignment?



Your analysis is almost correct.  The instruction mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + vptrs] can also execute as early as group 1—register renaming uncouples instructions from the names of the registers they use.
Note that the actual order in which the instructions are executed depends on the specific microarchitecture used.  Use a tool like uiCA to analyse this. (https://uica.uops.info/)
The byte ptr phrase indicates that the operand is a pointer to a byte, as opposed to a pointer to a quadword as with the other operands.

"Hence, the following instruction can execute as early as group 2" but that instruction depends on RDX, which depends on the shr.

movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rip + hash_shift] and mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + slots_strides] can run in parallel? I thought they could not because ecx is in rcx.

@Afshin: That's the whole point of register renaming as mentioned in the answer.  They write to different internal physical registers, and the machine keeps track of which physical register is rcx to each instruction.

@DarkAtom I actually missed that bit when I analysed the code, thank you for catching that.  Removed the wrong sentence.

@Afshin: If you're not familiar with how register renaming avoids Write After Write (WAW) hazards (as well as WAR), see the early part of my answer on Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)

shouldn't the second from last instruction be in group 5 (and thus the last one be in group 6)?

Thanks! I am still puzzled by the byte ptr. hash_shift is declared here: https://github.com/jll63/yomm2/blob/master/include/yorel/yomm2/policies/fast_perfect_hash.hpp#L26. A std::size_t, not a byte.

@yorel Only the least significant byte of hash_shift is required, which is why I guess the compiler decided to “optimise“ the load to a byte load.
